# https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh pull from server

Tags: android, android-layout, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to use https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh to implement pull-to-refresh. But I don't see where in the example to get data from my server. I am using observer pattern so that inside the `update` method I can call

```
mPullToRefresh.setRefreshComplete();
```

But where do I make the call to server?

By Observer pattern I mean that there is a class SynchDogs responsible for pulling from server. Then this Listview activity registers with SynchDogs as an observer. So where in the Pull-to-refresh pattern to I tell SynchDogs to synch with server? I am using the quick guide as

```
private void setupPullToRefresh() {
    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(this)
        .theseChildrenArePullable(R.id.dog_list)
        .listener(this)
        .setup(mPullToRefresh);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you start in the pull-to-refresh listener and then stop via setRefreshComplete when your job is finished

PS: better not use this lib any more https://plus.google.com/103829716466878605055/posts/8wmKAXEGAG2
there is now a SwipeRefreshLayout in the official lib

Comment: Thanks for the link +1 .Even after clicking on `Add Support Library` and choosing version 19, eclipse still can'f find `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` for the activity. Do you know how to get it?

Comment: do you know how I might get it? According to `Android SDK Manager` I already have both installed. So I am at a loss on how to get it into my project.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I find the lib. But I am not looking for an example on how to use it. I can't find one yet. I will ask a different question and link it here.

Comment: Here is the link to my new question. can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738522/simple-example-on-how-to-use-swiperefreshlayout-with-listview