# simple example on how to use SwipeRefreshLayout with ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

Does anyone have a simple example on how to use  SwipeRefreshLayout with a ListView? Here is my situation:

I have a class SynchDogs that pulls data from the server. So that class serves as the source for my adapter. I want to use  SwipeRefreshLayout for refreshing the adapter and so the ListView. DogActivity is an Observer of SynchDogs so that DogActivity implements an `update` method that is called when new data is ready.

So I implement `onRefresh` as

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    SynchDogs.getInstance().synchronizeWithServer();
}
```

So I am supposing this is all I need to initiate the start of pull-to-refresh. If so, inside `update` what do I do to end the call?

I also already have

```
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
        android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
        android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
        android.R.color.holo_red_light);
```

**update**

Basically, I want to know the call for stopping the color show.

Comment: Posted some sample code on GitHub: https://github.com/AndroidExamples/SwipeRefreshLayout-ListViewExample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call the method `setRefreshing(false)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setRefreshing(boolean)

Comment: Then maybe there is something else wrong with my code because I did that.

Comment: All I have to do is `swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false)` right?

Comment: Yep, I had a bug somewhere else.

Comment: i think this link might help,http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-swiperefreshlayout-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use this beautiful gist here.

Gist - https://gist.github.com/antoniolg/9837398

Blog - http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban : Thank you. Added the blog to the answer.

Comment: this tutorial can also be helpful: http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/playing-around-with-the-swiperefreshlayout/